# Custom notification Limit on Data Loading

Tags: lightning, process-builder, data-loader, notification

I have a process builder which fires custom notification to case owners when the case is updated.Its working fine in normal scenario.
But I needed to Data Load(Update) 200000+ records which inturn fired the process and as a result data didnot get updated and I am receiveing the Limit error:

**We can't save this record because the “###########” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. You've reached the limit of 10,000 notification actions per hour. Notification actions will start again in the next hour**

Is there a way I can bypass the process when dataloaded or any other way to avoid this error?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notif_builder_considerations.htm&type=5  check this once

Answer (score 1):

If it is a one-time request, go to Setup->Process Builder and deactivate the process for the time of the upload. Make sure that you do it in a timeframe where is no real notifications should be triggered.
If it is a reoccurring request to do such upload, add a checkbox on the object `Skip notification`. Set it to `TRUE` for the uploaded records and update the process builder to skip records which has this checkbox set to true.